# applescript 'Can’t make current application into type string'

Tags: shell, applescript

I am creating my first simple apple script.

Basically to start a shell script which will start running a program.
So I placed the shell script into the Resources/Scripts and am now trying to run this apple script:

```
do shell script (path to resource) & "Scripts/startWindows7.sh"
```

However this results into this error:

```
"Can’t make current application into type string." number -1700 from current application to string
```

I also tried to run this apple script:

```
do shell script (path to resource "Scripts/startWindows7.sh")
```

But this will result into an other error:

```
Can’t make alias into type string." number -1700 from alias Contents:Resources:Scripts:startWindows7.sh" to string
```

So there must be a better way to do this,
however I can't find the right solution on Google, nor can I find the right solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `POSIX path of (path to me)` to get the path to the application:

```
do shell script POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/script.sh"
```

The script has to be executable and include an interpreter line:

```
echo $'#!/bin/bash\nsay a'>Desktop/Untitled.app/Contents/Resources/script.sh
chmod +x Desktop/Untitled.app/Contents/Resources/script.sh
```